# What type is the number converted to if it is specified as interface in the structure for json

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a json in which the field can come as a string and as a number.

```
{"ID": 123456}
```

```
{"ID": "12345678"}
```

I need to process both options. I wrote through the interface and output the type to the log. My Id is always integer. Will the id always be float64 after unmarshal or can it have a different type ? I then need to bring any of the options to string

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/pquerna/ffjson/ffjson"
)

type Person struct {
    ID interface{}
}

func main() {
    var message = "{\"ID\": 123456}"
    var message1 = "{\"ID\": \"1234\"}"
    var person, person1 Person
    ffjson.Unmarshal([]byte(message), &person)
    ffjson.Unmarshal([]byte(message1), &person1)
    fmt.Printf("type=%T, value=%v\n ", person.ID, person)
    fmt.Printf("type=%T, value=%v\n ", person1.ID, person1)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/zgSv01-eiCN

Comment: *"Will the id always be float64"* -- Not if the JSON is string (e.g., `"12345678"`), regardless of the contents of that string, in which case the Go type would also be `string`.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it a little incorrectly. I meant if a number comes in, not a string, will there always be float64

Comment: The docs state that the ffjson package uses the standard json package by default, which is documented to use float64 for json numbers. Do you have a reason to assume something besides the documented behavior will happen?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason for using `ffjson`? It looks like it's not been touched since 2019.

I would recommend using the standard library's `encoding/json` as seen in the example below.
For numbers [you'll always get](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal) `float64`.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    ID interface{}
}

func main() {
    var message = "{\"ID\": 123456}"
    var message1 = "{\"ID\": \"1234\"}"
    var person, person1 Person
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(message), &person)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(message1), &person1)
    fmt.Printf("type=%T, value=%v\n", person.ID, person)
    fmt.Printf("type=%T, value=%v\n ", person1.ID, person1)
}
```

Output:

```
type=float64, value={123456}
type=string, value={1234}
```